# Remove Drive Map GPOs that are no longer being applied

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

I have a Windows 7 64-bit Pro laptop that had some GPOs on it (user and computer) for various things including some drive mappings that the laptop won't be able to access from its normal location. I rearranged my GPOs such that the laptop would not get the GPO for mapping these drives. I have managed to  change and update the GPOs on the client, but it is still trying to map those drives when I log in and it takes a good 30 seconds.

I know there are particular GPOs that won't get removed, even when leaving the domain. My coworker is telling me my best/only option is to start from scratch and rebuild the system. Is there a registry key I can delete that will get rid of the old drive map GPOs?

The server is Windows 2008 R2.

Comment: What sort of policy? User Configuration Preference? And have you tried manually disconnecting them?

Comment: User Configuration > Preferences > Windows Settings > Drive Maps.

Under that section I added a drive map via GPO, then unlinked the GPO. Even after gpupdating the clients they are trying to mount that drive.

Comment: Can you temporarily trip the "Remove policy when it falls out of scope" option? I find it's bad long term though.

Comment: I'm just going to reformat, I'm out of time and need to get this machine out.

Comment: Well, that will do it. Sorry I didn't have a better answer.